# 4 Band JPEG2000 compression for RGBNIR

Tags: image, compression

The South African National Mapping Agency acquires multispectral imagery (R,G,B and NIR)and currently compresses its aerial imagery with JPEG compression with a TIF wrapper. So we give out JPEG (Q3) compressed TIF files. This has a serious limitation in that it does not support 4 band compression. Due to this limitation we give our RGB.tif as well as CIR.tif. This situation has obvious duplication of bands.

We are thinking of moving to 4 band JPEG2000 compression for our workflow as well as giving clients 4 band orthorectified jp2 imagery.

Does JPEG2000 support this 4 band combination of (R,G,B,NIR) ?

Comment: JPEG2000 standard supports images with multiple bands (components). This article deals with compressing images with 224 bands http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=886630. R,G,B, NIR is not a problem. I believe that you can find 7 band Landsat samples and use QGIS for selecting three bands to be shown as R-G-B on the screen.

Comment: You could also do each band as a separate file, or use a container like (Geo)TIFF or NITF, which can do multiple bands.